# mysql - Order by from multiple tables in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, sql-order-by

I have 3 tables topic1, topic2, topic3. I split into 3 tables because of huge difference in attributes. all of these table has a common column of created_timestamp

I would like to create a timeline displaying from the latest with the created_timestamp as reference.

I have tried joining the tables and order by greatest (t1.created_timestamp, t2.created_timestamp, t3.created_timestamp) but I can't do this in the query builder of laravel.

Plus when displaying of the attributes, they will be repeated, is there a way to only show topic1 attributes if topic1 is the latest, so on and so forth.

Or is there a better method?

Thank you Jedi masters!

I forgot to mention about a fourth table (follower table) that only shows the created_by of the 3 topic tables.

```
topic1 {var1, var2, created_timestamp, user_id)
topic2 {var3, var2, var3, created_timestamp, teacher_id)
topic3 {var3, created_timestamp, visitor_id)
follower {follow_id, creator_id}
```

follow_id = user_id, teacher_id, visitor_id (table joins)
I would need to get only rows that I follow (aka where follower.creator_id = $me)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way would be to run a query for each table and then combine the results.

```
$a = DB::table('topic1')->join('follower', 'folower.follow_id', '=', 'topic1.user_id')->where('folower.follower_id', $followed)->get();
$b = DB::table('topic2')->join('follower', 'folower.follow_id', '=', 'topic2.teacher_id')->where('folower.follower_id', $followed)->get();
$c = DB::table('topic3')->join('follower', 'folower.follow_id', '=', 'topic3.visitor_id')->where('folower.follower_id', $followed)->get();

$results = new Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
$results = $results->merge($a)->merge($b)->merge($c)->sortBy('created_timestamp');
```

Comment: i think it is a little hard to do so in my case. i'm going to try your answer (which looks perfect) but i have another problem which i forgot to point out. terrible. a fourth table (follower) that only shows has a where created_by of all the 3 topics. is there a way to do this when i split the tables up?

Comment: You want to include the created_bys for each topic in the followers table into the final collection?

Comment: the following table has a follow_id that joins topic1.user_id, topic2.teacher_id and topic3.visitor_id. i would join the following on user_id, teacher_id and visitor_id and where follow_id = $variable_follow

Comment: I've updated my answer so that it joins on the followers table each time and makes sure the follower id is you.  I'm not sure why this is necessary when you can just make sure `topic1.user_id`, `topic2.teacher_id`, and `topic3.visitor_id` match your id.

Comment: thanks man! will take a look right away. topic1.user_id, topic2.teacher_id and topic3.visitor_id are only the joining factor. i would want the rows of these 3 tables based on follower.creator_id which is me. the follow_id is to join with the other 3 tables to get their rows.

Comment: however so unfortunately, follower also created_at, does it make it not work? because i think i tried what you just edited and exception was thrown, i'm guessing it's the ambiguous naming.

Comment: There shouldn't be any ambiguous naming looking at the table structure you've shown.  I think what happened is I was sorting by `created_at` when you stated the column name was `created_timestamp`.